# Where is my minecraft.jar for 1.10.2?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am looking for my minecraft.jar everywhere. The only thing in the `bin` folder is a folder labeled `backups`, and here's what I found in `versions`:

> 1.7.10
>
> 1.8
>
> 1.8-Forge11.14.3.1543
>
> 1.9.2
>
> 1.9.4
>
> 1.10
>
> 1.10.2
>
> 1.10.2-forge1.10.2-12.18.0.2008
>
> versions

Everything here is a folder except for `versions`, which is an Adobe Acrobat document. I am using Windows 10.

Where do I find the `minecraft.jar` for 1.10.2?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type in *%appdata%/.minecraft*. Then click on *versions*, and finally click on the version that you want your .jar for. (For example if i wanted 1.8.9.jar I would click on the 1.8.9 folder)

Answer (score 0):

For each version of the game, there's a seperate jar in that version's folder. If you want the jar for 1.10.2, it's in the 1.10.2 folder.

Comment: when i opened my 1.10.2 folder there was no jar